# Converting equatorial to alt-az coordinates is very slow

Tags: python, astropy

I'm trying to convert the equatorial coordinates of an object to alt-az coordinates for a given time & location in (hopefully) <5 sec runtime, or more ideally, <1 sec runtime.

Following the [astropy tutorial for coordinate transformations](http://learn.astropy.org/rst-tutorials/Coordinates-Transform.html#transform-frames-to-get-to-altitude-azimuth-altaz), I set up the following code:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord,EarthLocation, AltAz
from astropy.time import Time

target = SkyCoord(9.81625*u.deg, 0.88806*u.deg, frame='icrs')

location = EarthLocation(lat='31d57.5m', lon='-111d35.8m', height=0*u.m)
obs_time = Time('2010-12-21 1:00')

alt_az_frame = AltAz(location=location, obstime=obs_time)
target_alt_az = target.transform_to(alt_az_frame)

print(target_alt_az.alt, target_alt_az.az)
```

This code takes 20 seconds to run, almost all of which comes from the `target.transform_to(alt_az_frame)` line.

Is there a more appropriate way to use the `transform_to` function to speed up the code, or should I abandon using astropy altogether and write code from scratch? I understand there's a lot of extra functionality built into `SkyCoord` objects, much of which I likely don't need -- it's just convenient to use pre-built, standardized code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some debugging, it seems that it happens because `astropy.utils.iers.iers`'s `conf.iers_auto_url` is a bad url. Here is my simple solution for your problem.

```
from astropy.utils.iers.iers import conf
# The desired url may change in the future
conf.iers_auto_url = 'ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/products/iers/finals2000A.all'

# Run your code here
```

Alternatively, you can do things like `conf.remote_timeout = 0.1` or `conf.auto_download = False`(use backup data).

I couldn't find a document directly relevant to this issue but reading [this page](https://astropy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils/iers.html) may help.  This problem was discussed [in the issue](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/5059). I think this problem happens of only certain versions of the library, so updating the library to the latest version could be a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `conf.auto_download = False` because `conf.remote_timeout = 0.1` didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Alex Are you sure you want to disable auto_download? You can try setting `conf.iers_auto_url` directly to a valid url or updating your package.

Comment: Indeed, you can see that the correct URL is the default in the latest stable version of Astropy (v4.0) [here](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/763f069058cb1ee2038fa1cfa485452ec94b726e/astropy/utils/iers/iers.py#L48); it is used as the default value for `conf.iers_auto_url` [just below](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/763f069058cb1ee2038fa1cfa485452ec94b726e/astropy/utils/iers/iers.py#L117).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for quick conversions to alt-az then Astropy might not be the best tool. The Celest library does conversions from ECI and ECEF frames to altitude and azimuth in a fraction of the time (although it doesn't deal with equatorial conversions). Perhaps you could convert to ECI using astropy and do the horizontal conversion using Celest. Note that this library applies some simplifications but is still pretty accurate.

The following code should do the trick.

```py
from celest import Satellite, GroundPosition
import numpy as np

UTCTimeData = np.array(['2020-06-01 12:00:00.0340', ..., '2020-06-01 12:01:00.0340'])
ECIvec = np.array([[-4.46e+03, -5.22e+03, 1.75e-04], ..., [2.73e+03, 2.08e+03, -6.02e+03]])

toronto = GroundPosition(name="Toronto", coor=(43.662300, -79.394530))

finch = Satellite()
finch.getAltAz(groundPos=toronto, posData=ECIvec, timeData=UTCTimeData)
```

PyPI link: https://pypi.org/project/Celest/

A runtime comparison can be seen in this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blh5y.png).